# Flutter - I/Choreographer( 6998): Skipped 44 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, flutter, android-emulator

This problem started when I was using SQFlite. but now even if I open a different project it still skips certain frames. Can it be fixed I tried wipe data and even installed new emulator but the problem still remains. or is it just because my system.(ryzen 5 - 4500U , 8GB RAM, 512GB SSD)
**Thank you in advance**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.blue
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Shop App"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text("Add"),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: The code isn't showing any data intensive calculation on main thread. Is this the same code that skipped the frame then yes might be related to your computer. Run it on actual device.

Comment: Yes it is the same code. and i tried running it on my android device. may be its because of my computer. Thanks though